# Can't get manual cache expiry working in Rails development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm attempting to set up manual low-level cache expiry on Rails 4 in development. The cache expiry is triggered after a certain action in the view, which leads to a background job (using Delayed Job) that's actually a custom class containing the caching code.

This is the trigger:

```
if request.patch?
  @startup_funding = StartupFunding.where(id: params[:id]).first
  if @startup_funding.update_attributes(startup_funding_round_params)
    redirect_to unique_names_path(@startup_funding.startup.unique_names.unique_name)
    GraphUpdate.delay.update
  end
end
```

This is the custom class I'm using, which deletes the key and creates one from scratch:

```
class GraphUpdate < ActiveRecord::Base
  def update
    Rails.cache.delete('x')
    Rails.cache.fetch('x') do
        'test123'
    end
  end
end
```

I've activated caching in development.rb: `config.action_controller.perform_caching = true`

When I tried this initially without `cache.delete('x')`, I was able to successfully save 'x' as 'test', but it seems that the cache isn't expiring.

Not sure what went wrong. Also, If I implement this in Heroku, is there any special action I need to take or does it run out of the box?

Answer (score 0):

To expire the cache, you need to specify expiration time. Here's a [link to the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/Store.html#method-i-fetch). In short, you need to do the following:

```
Rails.cache.fetch('x', :expires_in => 60.seconds) { 'test123' }
```